# Parsing with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to count the number of lines contained by a file that looks like this:

```
-StartACheck
---Lines--
-EndACheck
-StartBCheck
---Lines--
-EndBCheck
```

with this:

```
count=0
z={}
for line in file:
      s=re.search(r'\-+Start([A-Za-z0-9]+)Check',line)
      if s:
           e=s.group(1)
           for line in file:
               z.setdefault(e,[]).append(count)
               q=re.search(r'\-+End',line)
               if q:
                   count=0
                   break

for a,b in z.items():
    print(a,len(b))
```

I want to basically store the number of lines present inside ACheck , BCheck etc in a dictionary but I keep getting the wrong output

Something like this

```
A,15
B,9
```

etc

Comment: Where is `count` defined?

Comment: I just defined count as 0 at the top.

Comment: Instead of using regex, just use a boolean variable to start or stop the count when Start or End is encountered

Comment: If I don't use Regex then I can't extract the "A" and "B".

Comment: Reset `count` after you reach the end of a group?

Comment: Doesn't work if I reset it either. Still get 2 in each group for some reason

Comment: Please edit your question to show your current code.

Comment: I edited it just now. Can you say what's wrong

Comment: `count` is defined and modified, but is never change its value. Variable names are unclear. `z` is not defined.

Comment: Count is just appending values to the key. I actually just measure the length of count to get the number of elements in each key. z is a dictionary . Edited them now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using something like:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)  # zero if key doesn't exists

for line in file:
    start = re.fullmatch('^Start([AB])Check\n$', line).groups()[0]
    end = re.fullmatch('^End([AB])Check\n$', line).groups()[0]
    if start:
        curr_key = group
    elif end:
        assert curr_key == group, "ending line {} doesn't match with an opening line for {}".format(line, curr_key)
        curr_key = None
    else:  # it's a normal line
        counts[curr_key] += 1
```

Bonus point: detect non-matching start-end lines + count lines outside start-end lines.

## Without defaultdict

Replace `else` clause by:

```
    else:  # it's a normal line
        if curr_key in counts:
            counts[curr_key] += 1
        else:
            counts[curr_key] = 1
```

And define `counts` as a regular dict:

```
counts = {}
```

## Fixing the given code

Given code seems working:

Here is a (apparently valid) file definition:

```
FILE = iter((  # generator of lines
    '-StartACheck',
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    '-EndACheck',
    '-StartBCheck',
    'a',
    'b',
    '-EndBCheck',
))
```

Here is the missing definitions:

```
import re
z = {}
```

And the provided code:

```
count=0
for line in FILE:
      s=re.search(r'\-+Start([A-Za-z0-9]+)Check',line)
      if s:
           e=s.group(1)
           for line in FILE:
               z.setdefault(e,[]).append(count)
               q=re.search(r'\-+End',line)
               if q:
                   count=0
                   break

for a,b in z.items():
    print(a,len(b))
```

Output is:

```
A 4
B 3
```

Which is accurate, as the first line (`StartACheck`) is counted:

```
      if s:
           e=s.group(1)
           for line in FILE:
               z.setdefault(e,[]).append(count)  # first called with the Start line
```

---

Error could be around the file lines extraction : if the file is read as:

```
file = tuple(open('filename.ext'))
```

Then the double for-loop of the source code iterates over each line of the file for each line of the file. Example:

```
filelines = (1, 2, 3, 4)
for line in filelines:
    for line in filelines:
        print(line)
```

And the (valid in this case) almost identical:

```
filelines = iter((1, 2, 3, 4))
for line in filelines:
    for line in filelines:
        print(line)
```

Comment: I can't use defaultdict. Can you do something without defaultdict?

Comment: defaultdict is available in `stdlib`. You should use it anywhere it is necessary. However, i've added a patch to the code that made it works with `counts` defined as a `dict`.

Comment: Can't use fullmatch either. Anyways can you look into my implementation and say what's wrong?

Comment: Thanks a lot but for some reason it doesn't. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Maybe the reading of the file, as shown at the end of my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't too big (say, smaller than 1GB or so), I'd just read the whole thing and call `re.findall()`:

```
import re
result = {
    name: lines.count('\n')
    for name, lines in
    re.findall(r'^-Start([A-Za-z0-9]+)Check$(.*)^-End\1Check$',
               open('x.in').read(),
               re.DOTALL + re.MULTILINE)
    }
print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the pattern of

```
-StartACheck
--- Line 1
-EndACheck
-StartBCheck
---Line 1
-EndBCheck
-StartACheck
---Line 1
---Line 2
---Line 3
-EndACheck
```

You can use a multi-line regex to capture the blocks that start with `-Start[pattern]Check` and end with `-End[pattern]Check` with something like this:

```
^-Start([A-Za-z0-9]+)Check$(.*?)^-End(?:\1)Check$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oD8aW5/3)

In Python, you can combine that with `re.finditer` and a `Counter` like so:

```
import re
from collections import Counter
pattern=r'^-Start([A-Za-z0-9]+)Check$(.*?)^-End(?:\1)Check$'

c=Counter()
with open(fn, "r") as f:
    for m in re.finditer(pattern, f.read(), re.S | re.M):
        c+=Counter({m.group(1): len(m.group(2).splitlines())-1})
```

Prints:

```
Counter({'A': 4, 'B': 1})
```

If you are concerned about reading the entire file into memory, use a `mmap` of the file like so:

```
import re
from collections import Counter
import mmap
pattern=r'^-Start([A-Za-z0-9]+)Check$(.*?)^-End(?:\1)Check$'

c=Counter()
with open(fn, "r+") as f:
    mm=mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    for m in re.finditer(pattern, mm, re.S | re.M):
        c+=Counter({m.group(1): len(m.group(2).splitlines())-1})
```

Then the OS will manage reading the file in appropriate chunks to match the regex.